# Отправка сообщений телеграмм бота в определенную дату

Tags: python, telebot, время, python-telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

В первый раз делаю телеграмм бота и хочу чтобы он мне прислал сообщение в определенный месяц, день, время пишу бота на Pyton через библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI  мне интересно возможно ли это вообще сделать

Comment: Однозначно возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно понимать что в отличие от классической обработки входящего запроса (сообщения или команды от пользователя) боту придется самостоятельно инициировать отправку сообщения

Это не сложно, однако потребуется учесть два аспекта:

1. Придется хранить информацию о пользователе (chat_id)
2. Потребуется крон(crontab) с некоторым расписанием который пройдется по пользователям в базе и инициирует отправку сообщений